# Is using of "Durable Object" a good practice in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

According to the definition in Douglas Crockford's book, "JavaScript: The Good Parts", a **durable object** is an object in the functional style which all its methods make no use of *this* or *that*. Please look into the following examples:

This is an example of durable object:

```
const MyObj = function()
{
  const myObj = BaseObject();

  const inp = create( "input" );
  inp.type = "checkbox";
  const txt = doc.createTextNode("");
  myObj.control = create( "label" );
  myObj.control.appendChild( inp );
  myObj.control.appendChild( txt );

  myObj.setState = state => inp.checked = state;

  myObj.getState = () => inp.checked;

  myObj.setCaption = cap =>
  {
    txt.textContent = cap;
  }
  return myObj;
}
```

This is an example of non-durable object:

```
const MyObj = function()
{
  const myObj = BaseObject();

  myObj.inp = create( "input" );
  myObj.inp.type = "checkbox";
  myObj.txt = doc.createTextNode("");
  myObj.control = create( "label" );
  myObj.control.appendChild( myObj.inp );
  myObj.control.appendChild( myObj.txt );

  myObj.setState = function(state)
  { 
      this.inp.checked = state; **// Look at here**
  }

  myObj.getState = function() 
  {
      return this.inp.checked;
  }

  myObj.setCaption = cap =>
  {
    this.txt.textContent = cap;
    this.callABaseObjectMethode(); **// Look at here**
  }
  return myObj;
}
```

I want to know whether it is a good practice to have durable object (this-free) or not. Important factors are performance, security, scalability, flexibility of our JavaScript code.

Comment: Switch to ES6 class definitions, extending and etc or use `prototypes`

Comment: "*all its methods make no use of `this` or `that`*" - what do you think `myObj` is if not a "that" variable? Renaming it doesn't help.

Comment: I hear `durable object` first time. I know mutable and immutable objects. I know encapsulation techniques. So what You've wrote is just playing with private variable. and `this` is just reference to context where function was called.

Comment: btw Good Parts is a old book (2008). So after reading that book look for something that explains ES6, ES7

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your comment. I changed the answer a little bit. Also please be noted that in the book, the writer says that "all the methods of object make no use of *this* or *that*"

Answer (score 0):

Both of Your examples not good example.

Both of them allocate memory for methods every time.

Your `myObj` in the beginning has `BaseObject`'s methods, fields. But after You say: `allocate memory for setState method and attach to instance`

So here comes `prototypes` :

```
MyObj.prototype.setState = state => this._state = state;

MyObj.prototype.getState = () => Object.assign({}, this._state);
```

Prototypes are static objects that being allocated once and associated to instances of classes.

Now let's make component from Your code (just for fun):

```js
class Component 
{

  constructor(initialState) {
    this._state = initialState ? initialState : {};
    this._masterNode = document.createElement(this.constructor.name);
    this._eventListeners = {};
  }

  createElement(tagName, attributes = {}, onStateChange) {
    const element = document.createElement(tagName);
    Object.assign(element, attributes);
    if (onStateChange) {
      this.on('stateChanged', (newState) => {
        onStateChange(newState, element);
      });
    }
    return element;
  }

  createInput(name, type, onStateChange) {
    return this.createElement('input', {name, type}, onStateChange);
  }

  createLabel(labelFor, onStateChange) {
    return this.createElement('label', {for: labelFor}, onStateChange);
  }

  createTextNode(text, onStateChange) {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    if (onStateChange) {
      this.on('stateChanged', (newState) => {
        onStateChange(newState, textNode);
      });
    }
    return textNode;
  }

  appendChild(element) {
    this._masterNode.appendChild(element);
  }
  
  setState(state) {
    Object.assign(this._state, state);
    this.emit('stateChanged', this._state);
  }
  
  getState() {
    return Object.assign({}, this._state);
  }
  
  on(eventName, listener) {
    if (!this._eventListeners[eventName]) this._eventListeners[eventName] = [];
    this._eventListeners[eventName].push(listener);
  }
  
  emit(eventName, payload) {
    if (!this._eventListeners[eventName]) return;
    console.log(eventName, payload);
    this._eventListeners[eventName].forEach(method => {
      method(payload);
    });
  }
  
  appendTo(container) {
    container.appendChild(this._masterNode);
  }
}

const form = new Component();

// create label
const label = form.createLabel('termsAndConditions');

// create checkbox with state listener
const checkbox = form.createInput('something', 'checkbox',
  (newState, element) => {
    if (newState.agreedWithTC === true) {
      element.checked = true;
      return;
    }
    element.checked = false;
  });
  
// operating with state on click by checkbox
checkbox.onclick = () => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    form.setState({agreedWithTC: true});
    return;
  }
  form.setState({agreedWithTC: false});
};


// append checkbox to label
label.appendChild(checkbox);

const textNode = form.createTextNode('Agree with T&C', 
  (newState, element) => {
    textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace('(agreed)', '').replace('(not agreed)', '');
    if (newState.agreedWithTC === true) {
      textNode.textContent += ' (agreed)';
      return;
    }
    textNode.textContent += ' (not agreed)';
  });

// create text node and append it to label
label.appendChild(textNode);

// append label to form
form.appendChild(label);

// append overall component instance to container
form.appendTo(document.getElementById('container'));



setInterval(() => {
  form.setState({agreedWithTC: !form.getState().agreedWithTC});
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I read several articles to not use "class" in JavaScript like [this](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e)

Comment: I think You've to work with Babel, WebPack and get taste of ES6, ES7 and TypeScript